# Dynamically changing frame in html

Tags: html

I want to add a frame around a block in html. That block includes some pictures, tables and writings etc. To be able to do that, I am using the codes below. ( CODES INPUT are the codes that i call tables, pictures etc.)

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .myframe{
        height:1960px;
        width: 917px;
        border: 2px solid #25343B;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    </style>




    <div class="myframe"> 

    CODES INPUT

      CODES INPUT

         CODES INPUT

    </div>
```

However, I want to do that dynamically. In other words, since I define the length and height of my frame at the beginning, my frame's size is constant. But what i want to achieve is that, what ever I put inside the codes (say a million pictures), automatically a frame should cover the around of the contents. So, the length and height of the frame should be a bit greater than the total length and height of the things inside.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: No need of defining height and width. Because if u add the content dynamically, the div expands based on content.

Comment: OMG..Is it that simple? :) Thank you...